# Passar state de uma classe para um Modal em React Native

Tags: javascript, react, react-native

Estou iniciando em React Native e estou com um problema, vou colocar os prints para ficar mais fácil. Tenho uma tela chamada Perguntas, que tem um state inicial, e essa tela abre um modal chamado Atencao (como na imagem abaixo)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso passar essa variável posto, que está no state da tela Perguntas e será alterada nessa tela, para o Modal Atencao, mas não sei como fazer isso. Já tentei algumas coisas e nada funcionou. Alguém sabe o que deveria usar pra isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara, posso estar errado porque não entendi muito bem o teu problema, mas pela tua pergunta,parece que você teria que adicionar isso aqui:

```
<Atencao posto={this.state.posto} />
```

E depois só acessar no modal pelo props, se não era esse o problema, da um reply aí pra tentar explicar melhor.

Comment: Era isso sim. Agora acho que vai funcionar. Era muito simples e eu procurando coisa elaborada kkkk Mt obrigado

Comment: @JohannArouca show! qualquer problema pode dar um mention aí e a gente tenta resolver.